# Onended switch to Next track

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, recursion

I'm trying to build an MP3 player. Here I want to perform a switch to the next song once the current tack ends.

Here is a part of my code:

```js
function clicki(ID, norrnd) {

  if (norrnd == 'nor') {
    $('.liActive').removeClass('liActive');
    $('#' + ID).next().addClass('liActive');

    // Set track Data
    $('audio').attr('id', 'audioNor');
    $('audio').attr('src', $('.liActive').attr('rel'));

    // Play
    var player = $('.tbd').get(0);
    player.play();
    $('#pause').removeClass('hi');

    $(player).bind('ended', clicki(ID++, 'nor')); //as well as .onfinish result in TOO MUCH RECURSION error.
  }
}
```

```html
<audio controls id="" class="tbd" type="audio/mpeg" src="Ella Fitzgerald - It Don't Mean a Thing.mp3"></audio>
```

So when I just initiate `clicki()` first time the page instantly freezes:

> Too Much Recursion.

How do I make the track be automatically switched with no Recursion flood?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're calling the function immediately -- you need to create a function around it:

```
function clicki(ID, norrnd) {
  if (norrnd === 'nor') {
    $('.liActive').removeClass('liActive');
    $('#' + ID).next().addClass('liActive');

    // Set track Data
    $('audio').attr('id', 'audioNor');
    $('audio').attr('src', $('.liActive').attr('rel'));

    // Play
    var $player = $('.tbd');;
    $player.get(0).play();
    $('#pause').removeClass('hi');

    // if you call it now, it's going to keep calling itself
    $player.bind('ended', function () {
      clicki(ID++, 'nor');
    });
  }
}
```